# Python PEMDAS calculator

Tags: python, complexity, math-expression-eval

The goal of this calculator is to evaluate an expression with PEMDAS in mind (no parenthesis yet, adding soon). Although the program works, I want to make it as efficient as possible with the approach I used to attack the mathematical expression.

So the way I decided to approach the problem is to initially organize the expression via my `cleanUp()` so that it's easier to manipulate/iterate afterwards, for example:

"`2+2  -4   * 1 /     3.344 - -2`" becomes "`2 + 2 - 4 * 1 / 3.344 + 2`"
which can now be easily split by a space and the calculation process is now a lot easier, but I feel like my `cleanUp()` function can be a lot more efficient. (I'm still learning Time complexities of built-in functions of Python 3)

Here is my whole code, feel free to comment on any other part of the program, but I'm mostly asking for optimization improvements on the `cleanUp()` function.

```
import time

def isNumber(s):
    #s must be a non-empty string
    #returns True if it's convertible to float, else False
    if (len(s)==0 and not s =='') or not isinstance(s, str):
        print("type mismatch error: isNumber")
        return "type mismatch error: isNumber"
    try:
        s = float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        #print("type mismatch error: isNumber")
        return False


def cleanUp(s):
    priorSpace = True
    inDecimal = False
    ops = ["+","-","*","/","^"]
    s = s.replace("+", " + ").replace("-", " - ").replace("*", " * ").replace("/", " / ").replace("^", " ^ ")
    st = list(s)
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if (not isNumber(c) and c not in ops) and priorSpace:
            if c == "." and not inDecimal:
                inDecimal = True
            elif c == "." and inDecimal:
                st[i] = ""
            else:
                st[i] = ""
                inDecimal = False
        elif (not isNumber(c) and c not in ops) and not priorSpace:
            if c == "." and not inDecimal:
                inDecimal = True
            elif c == "." and inDecimal:
                st[i] = ""
            else:
                st[i] = " "
                priorSpace = True
                inDecimal = False
        else:
            priorSpace = False
    final = ''.join(st).strip().split(' ')
    if '-' in final[0]:
        del final[0]
        final[0] = '-' + final[0]
    newNumber, newOpr, oprPos = getNextNumber(final, 0)
    if oprPos == None:
        return newNumber
    cacheNum=newNumber
    pos=oprPos+1                #the new current position
    opr=newOpr
    while pos<(len(final)-1):
        newNumber, newOpr, oprPos = getNextNumber(final, pos)
        if (newOpr == None):
            break
        if (not isNumber(newNumber) and newNumber == '-'):
            del final[oprPos-1] #BOOKMARK
            final[oprPos-1] = '-' + final[oprPos-1]
        if (not isNumber(newNumber) and newNumber != '-'):
            print("error at line AB", newNumber)
            return "error at line AB"
        pos=oprPos+1
    return (final)


def getNextNumber(expr, pos):
    #expr is a given arithmetic formula in string
    temp = expr
    #pos = start position in expr
    #1st returned value = the next number (None if N/A)
    #2nd returned value = the next operator (None if N/A)
    #3rd retruned value = the next operator position (None if N/A)
    ops = ["+","-","*","/"]
    if len(expr)==0 or pos<0 or pos>=len(expr) or not isinstance(pos, int):
        print("type mismatch error: getNextNumber")
        return None, None, "type mismatch error: getNextNumber"
    #--- function code starts ---#
    res3 = 0
    res2 = 0
    if (pos+1) < len(temp):
        res3 = pos+1
        res2 = temp[pos+1]
    else:
        res3 = None
        res2 = None
    return ((temp[pos], res2, res3))



    #--- function code ends ---#


def exeOpr(num1, opr, num2):
    #This is a simple utility function skipping type check
    if opr=="+":
        return num1+num2
    elif opr=="-":
        return num1-num2
    elif opr=="*":
        return num1*num2
    elif opr=="/":
        return num1/num2
    elif opr=="^":
        return num1**num2
    else:
        return None


def calc(expr):
    #expr: nonempty string that is an arithmetic expression
    #the fuction returns the calculated result
    expr = cleanUp(expr)
    if len(expr)<=0:
        print("argument error: line A in eval_expr")        #Line A
        return "argument error: line A in eval_expr"
    #Hold two modes: "addition" and "multiplication"
    #Initializtion: get the first number
    newNumber, newOpr, oprPos = getNextNumber(expr, 0)
    ops = ["^","*","/","+","-"]
    if newNumber is None or not isNumber(newNumber):
        print("input formula error: line B in eval_expr")   #Line B
        return "input formula error: line B in eval_expr"
    elif newOpr is None or not newOpr in ops:
        return newNumber
    cacheNum=newNumber
    pos=oprPos+1                #the new current position
    opr=newOpr                  #the new current operator
    #start the calculation. Use the above functions effectively.
    new_expr = expr
    while True:
        newNumber, newOpr, oprPos = getNextNumber(new_expr, pos)
        #print(cacheNum, opr, newNumber, "The next opr however is", newOpr)
        if (not isNumber(newNumber)):
            print("input formula error: line C in eval_expr")   #Line C
            return "input formula error: line C in eval_expr"
        if (newOpr == None):
            break
        if(newOpr == "^"):
            temp = getNextNumber(new_expr, oprPos+1)[0]
            if (not isNumber(temp)):
                print("input formula error: line D in eval_expr")   #Line D
                return "input formula error: line D in eval_expr"
            #print("Weee", newOpr, newNumber, "with", temp)
            subs = exeOpr(float(newNumber), newOpr, float(temp))
            del new_expr[oprPos-1]
            del new_expr[oprPos-1]
            new_expr[oprPos-1] = str(subs)
            #print("The new expression to start calculating is: " + new_expr)
        elif((newOpr == "*" or newOpr == "/") and (opr not in ["^","*","/"])):
            temp, temp_Opr, temp_Pos = getNextNumber(new_expr, oprPos+1)
            #print("uhhh", temp_Opr)
            if temp_Opr == "^":
                temp2 = getNextNumber(new_expr, oprPos+3)[0]
                if (not isNumber(temp)):
                    print("input formula error: line D in eval_expr")   #Line D
                    return "input formula error: line D in eval_expr"
                #print("We", temp_Opr, temp, "with", temp2)
                subs = exeOpr(float(temp), temp_Opr, float(temp2))
                del new_expr[temp_Pos-1]
                del new_expr[temp_Pos-1]
                new_expr[temp_Pos-1] = str(subs)
                #print("The new expression to start calculating is: " + new_expr)
            else:
                if (not isNumber(temp)):
                    print("input formula error: line D in eval_expr")   #Line D
                    return "input formula error: line D in eval_expr"
                #print("Weee", newOpr, newNumber, "with", temp)
                subs = exeOpr(float(newNumber), newOpr, float(temp))
                del new_expr[oprPos-1]
                del new_expr[oprPos-1]
                new_expr[oprPos-1] = str(subs)
                #print("The new expression to start calculating is: " + new_expr)
        elif((newOpr == "+" or newOpr == "-") and opr not in ["+","-"]):
            subs = exeOpr(float(cacheNum), opr, float(newNumber))
            del new_expr[pos-2]
            del new_expr[pos-2]
            new_expr[pos-2] = str(subs)
            cacheNum=str(subs)
            opr=newOpr
            #print("The new expressionn to start calculating is: " + new_expr)
        else:
            subs = exeOpr(float(cacheNum), opr, float(newNumber))
            del new_expr[pos-2]
            del new_expr[pos-2]
            new_expr[pos-2] = str(subs)
            #print("The new expression to start calculating is: " + new_expr)
            cacheNum=str(subs)
            opr=newOpr
    subs = exeOpr(float(cacheNum), opr, float(newNumber))
    #print(new_expr)
    del new_expr[new_expr.index(cacheNum)]
    del new_expr[new_expr.index(opr)]
    new_expr[new_expr.index(newNumber)] = str(subs)
    return float(new_expr[0])

print(calc("2+2 -4 * 1 / 3.344 - -2")
```

Comment: Your last line is missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: @Ludisposed Fixed it to work, lemme know if you still run into it.

Comment: The last version returns `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-2']` which is not `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '+', '2']` as advertized by the post.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yeah I forgot to change that, but they both evaluate to the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire `cleanUp` method can be changed with almost **1** regular expression

Take the example:

```
import re
def clean(s):
    return re.split("([+\-\/*])", s.replace(" ", ""))

>>> print(clean("2+2 -4 * 1 / 3.344 - -2"))
>>> ['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '', '-', '2']
```

This is almost the same as your output only difference is, it adds an empty `''` when there are 2 operaters after eachother.

This can be fixed using a bit of list slicing, making the clean look like this:

```
import re
def clean(s):
    cleaned_expr = re.split("([+\-\/*])", s.replace(" ", ""))
    while '' in cleaned_expr:
        # Remove empty and concat operator to next number
        i = cleaned_expr.index('')
        cleaned_expr[i] = cleaned_expr[i+1] + cleaned_expr[i+2]
        del cleaned_expr[i+1:i+3]
    return cleaned_expr

>>> print(clean("2+2 -4 * 1 / 3.344 - -2"))
>>> ['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-2']
>>> print(clean("2+2- -4 * 1 / 3.344 -2"))
>>> ['2', '+', '2', '-', '-4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '2']
```

---

Some other minor **[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)** improvements are:

1. naming of functions should be `clean_up()` instead of `cleanUp`
2. Missing whitespaces around operators like `=`
3. Missing whitespace around `,`

---

## Note

In retrospect and Thanks to [@Mathias](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger) your `calc()` feels buggy, as an honest reviewer I would recommend it handles input like this `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-', '2']` when that is fixed I'm tempted to give another look at it, for now it just feels too buggy.

```
# The cleanest clean (but incorrect output for your calc)
import re
def clean(s):
    s = re.split("([+\-\/*])", s.replace(" ", ""))
    return [token for token in s if token]

>>> print(clean("2+2 -4 * 1 / 3.344 - -2"))
>>> ['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-', '2']
```

Comment: That wil not work since, his `calc()` will break at this input `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-', '2']`

Comment: In the end I think it would be best if it handles `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-', '2']` that output, since it is cleaner then `['2', '+', '2', '-', '4', '*', '1', '/', '3.344', '-', '-2']`

Comment: Thinking back at it, neither version handle the case of `2---2` (should they? Python returns `0`) as `['2', '-', '-', '-', '2']` is returned… So yes, better keep `clean` simple and fix `calc` instead…

Comment: I think to return `0` is a perfectly valid answer since `2 - + 2 = 0` it feels like I adapt `clean()` to work for `calc()` while perhaps it be better to fix `calc()` first

Comment: Then `return [token for token in cleaned_expr if token]` should do instead of the `while` loop ;)

Comment: for expressions like `2---2` I would just return an error, as for me it would deem as an invalid expression ( I mean nobody really sees this in an actual expression, regardless if python can handle it)

Comment: But what about handling multiple spaces in between numbers/operators?

Comment: @Vikaton regarding `2---2` it is valid math so why not handle it? Run the `clean()` and you'll see spaces are removed by the `replace(" ","")`

Comment: @Ludisposed Could you try inputting `-3.0^2.5` as an input to try? Im getting something thats actually not even a number...

Comment: @Vikaton You should add `^` as a token in the split thus split will be`re.split("([+\-\/*^])")`

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the fact, that your code is not running properly as it returns

```
input formula error: line C in eval_expr
input formula error: line C in eval_expr
```

with the example input, I'd suggest simplifying your module to

```
from re import compile

ARITHMETIC_EXPRESSIONS = compile('[0-9]*( ){0,}([+-/*^]( ){0,}[0-9]*( ){0,})*')
LEADING_ZEROS = compile('^0+(?=.)')


def coerce_python_syntax(string):
    """Converts arithmetic expression to python syntax."""

    string = string.replace('^', '**')
    return LEADING_ZEROS.sub('', string)


def calc(string):
    """Calculates the arithmetic expression given by string."""
    if ARITHMETIC_EXPRESSIONS.fullmatch(string):
        return eval(coerce_python_syntax(string))

    raise ValueError('String is not a safe arithmetic expression.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(calc("2+2 -4 * 1 / 3.344 - -2"))
```

since you are implementing basic arithmetic evaluation that python already has down cold.

Comment: Until something like: `eval("os.system('rm -rf /')")` comes along >;)

Comment: Ahh I see `.fullmatch` now. I stand corrected, but still I hope you see, why `eval` is `evil`

Comment: Without sanitizing the input, definitely.

Comment: The regex does miss a few, like operater `^` also try `calc("01 + 10")` or how about a CPU-burner attack? Stuff like  `2**9999999999**9999999`

Comment: Point is you'll end up with something quite long if you want to protect yourself for all, [safe python](https://opensourcehacker.com/2014/10/29/safe-evaluation-of-math-expressions-in-pure-python/)

Comment: Protection is already given by the `ARITHMETIC_EXPRESSIONS` regex. I added the missing operator, as well as coercing a valid python input, substituting the `^` operator and removing leading zeros.

Comment: Also interesting: [evalidate](http://evalidate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Not trying to bash you or anything, I just find this topic interesting :)

Comment: Is there maybe optimization improvements I can do with using 1exec` or `eval` ?

Comment: Also I fixed the error with that bug :)